# Create-React-App Jest failing: test suite must contain at least one test - but it does

Tags: redux, react-redux, jestjs

I have a react-redux app that I have initiated from create-react-app. From my understanding, what is needed to run jest is already configured for you in create-react-app(i.e. webpack files, babel, etc).

So I have create a test suite called `CreateQueryActions.test.js` and this files contains one test suite with all necessary components (to the best of my knowledge) - describe/it/expect.

When I run `npm run test` jest sees the file but it fails with `Test suite failed to run Your test suite must contain at least one test.`

but it does have a test. So whats happening here?

```
import { tableList } from "../../utils/CreateQueryMockData";
import * as createQueryActions from "./CreateQueryActions";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import fetchMock from "fetch-mock";
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';

//Async test dependencies
const middleware = [thunk];
const mockStore = configureMockStore(middleware);

describe("create query API calls", () => {
    afterEach(() => {
        /*Its importatnt to keep this test atomic. 
        * This initialized fetchMock for each test -
        * needs to be reset after each test has ran
        * */
        fetchMock.restore();
    });

    it("should create a 'GET_TABLE_LIST' action", () => {
        fetchMock.mock("*", {
            body: tableList,
            headers: { "content-type": "application/json" }
        });

        const expectedAction = [
            { type: "GET_TABLE_LIST" }
        ];

        const store = mockStore({ tableList: [] });
        return store.dispatch(createQueryActions.getTableList()).then(() => {
            expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expectedAction);
        });
    });

});
```

PACKAGE.JSON

```
{
  "name": "queryapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "history": "^4.9.0",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^0.19.1",
    "jest": "^24.7.1",
    "oidc-client": "^1.8.2",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
    "react-csv": "^1.1.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-redux": "^5.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.1",
    "react-table": "^6.10.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-form": "^7.4.2",
    "redux-form-validators": "^2.7.5",
    "redux-oidc": "^3.1.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "fetch-mock": "^7.3.9",
    "redux-immutable-state-invariant": "^2.1.0",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`afterEach`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/setup-teardown.html) is not a test case. It is used to perform some task after each test case. Your test case should be like below:

```
describe("create query API calls", () => {
        it("should create a 'GET_TABLE_LIST' action", () => {
            fetchMock.mock("*", {
                body: tableList,
                headers: { "content-type": "application/json" }
            });

            const expectedAction = [
                { type: "GET_TABLE_LIST" }
            ];

            const store = mockStore({ tableList: [] });
            return                                                                                                    store.dispatch(createQueryActions.getTableList()).then(() => {
                expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expectedAction);
        });
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Mukesh - that wasn't exactly the issue but you did allow me to see what was wrong. I do need the after each statement because its important to keep the test atomic - the function needed to initialize fetchMock.restore after each test, the problem was I had wrapped the test in the afterEach function as well which, as you pointed out was incorrect.The test now runs successfully.

Comment: Welcome... Happy to help